# Does cn1 provide App Review Plugin for users to send review within my cn1 app?

Tags: codenameone

Does cn1 provide App Review Plugin?
The users of my app could send reviews within my cn1 app?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did one a [while back](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/rating-widget.html), but it isn't good. Newer appstore requirements demand a native rating widget as far as I know. I'm not sure if this is enforced though. On the other hand, it should be pretty simple to add something like that since it's probably just a simple native call on iOS and Android.

Comment: Thank you. It seems I should learn how to call native ios&android from cn1 project. Do you have any resources for calling the native API form cn1?

Comment: Sure, the developer guide has a lot of information about it. Notice it predates the maven plugin change but everything should be the same. Just the location of the native code would be in the respective subproject.

Comment: Would you provide app review plug-in?
It really helps market my app.

Comment: I suggest filing an RFE in the project. I'll mark it as a "good first issue" since it should be relatively simple.

Comment: Would you add a comment once you finish this issue? Thank you.

Comment: You can file an issue [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/]. We probably won't do it but it will be visible to community members who want to contribute to Codename One and might decide to pick it up. You'll get notified of such updates via the issue tracker.

Comment: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3665

Comment: Is there anyone solving this issue? Is it time to resolve this issue?

Comment: I assigned it to Steve. I don't know when it can fit into his schedule especially with the holidays etc.

Comment: Have this issue solved?

Comment: No. After several community attempts I reassigned it to Steve but he has a lot on his plate so it will probably take a while for him to get there. I suggest pinging him on the issue to see if he has an ETA.